# trying to install mmoreram/gearman-bundle gives error on symfony 2.7

Tags: php, symfony, gearman, symfony-2.7

Looks like I'm missing something or maybe wrong doctrine version.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'The service "gearman.cache.wrapper" has a dependency on a non-existent service "doctrine_cache.providers.gearman_cache".' in /home/vagrant/Code/backend-symfony-dev/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php on line 58

Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The service "gearman.cache.wrapper" has a dependency on a non-existent service "doctrine_cache.providers.gearman_cache". in /home/vagrant/Code/backend-symfony-dev/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php on line 58

My composer.json require

```
"require" : {
"php" : ">=5.3.3",
"symfony/symfony" : "2.7.*",
"doctrine/orm" : "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "~1.2",
"twig/extensions" : "~1.0",
"symfony/assetic-bundle" : "~2.3",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle" : "~2.3",
"symfony/monolog-bundle" : "~2.4",
"sensio/distribution-bundle" : "~2.3",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle" : "~3.0",
"sensio/generator-bundle" : "~2.3",
"incenteev/composer-parameter-handler" : "~2.0",
"braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle" : "~2.0",
"twbs/bootstrap" : "3.0.*",
"jquery/jquery" : "1.10.*",
"knplabs/knp-menu-bundle" : "~2.0",
"knplabs/knp-menu" : "~2.0",
"knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle" : "~2.4",
"symfony/debug" : "~2.6",
"symfony/web-profiler-bundle" : "2.6.4",
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "1.3.5",
"mailgun/mailgun-php": "~1.7.2",
 "rollbar/rollbar": "~0.18.2",
"knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.4",
"h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "^0.12.3",
"liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.1",
"mmoreram/gearman-bundle": "3.0.5"            
}
```

I added the following to $bundles in appKernel.php

```
new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle(),
new Mmoreram\GearmanBundle\GearmanBundle()
```

Note say to use "Use tags lower than 4.X for Symfony 2.X versions", thus I'm using 3.0.5.  I also tried using lower version but end up with different error still related to doctrine though.  I have gearman installed on my system as well.  So a bit titled on what I'm missing.

https://github.com/mmoreram/GearmanBundle

https://gearmanbundle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: v2.7 is unsupported. You should at least upgrade to v2.8 which isn't to hard.

Comment: where did you get from.   I only see a note "Since Symfony2 versions 2.1 and 2.2 are not maintained anymore, and since these branches were in sync with master branch, they both have been deleted"

Comment: Sorry, that was just a side note, I dont know if 2.8 would fix your problem. https://symfony.com/roadmap/2.7